# How to get streched water reflections without changing rougness

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I have this render and I'm just trying to get the water reflections right. Basically what I want to achieve is to get the moon reflection to stretch across a bigger part of the lake like on this image [image: Image 1]

But now the water looks like plastic.. So I want to keep the reflections clear like on this image [image]

Is this possible or nonsense? Feel free to give some other suggestions too if you see something you think would make the render better :)

Comment: Is there a ground plane under the water to reflect any light?

Comment: And/or make the water volumetric to increase dispersion

Comment: So I just tried both, but the volumetric water completely screwed up my reflections, and the plane for reflections under the water didn't seem to have any effect